# how to upgrade the package version in Synaptic, when the latest version is not supported in Synaptic

Tags: package, igraph

I want to install the package libigraph-dev and libigraph2 in Synaptic, but they are only provided with version 0.9.6 while the latest version are already 0.10.4 in official website (https://igraph.org/c/).

Environment: Ubuntu 22.04

I tried to use the "force version" function in Synaptic but it's disabled.

How can I install the latest version with Synaptic (which means not manually)?

Comment: You can always compile igraph from sources. Instructions are here: https://igraph.org/c/html/latest/igraph-Installation.html This is not a difficult procedure. igraph can even be compiled without any dependencies. Don't be discouraged.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you! I have solved this problem. If you post this answer in the answer box, I can set it as the right answer.